# Как запустить метод после вызова метода OnGUI() в EditorWindow?

Tags: unity3d, события, gui

[Тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) нашёл порядок выполнения функций событий. Но так и не понял как запустить метод, после события отрисовки GUI (void OnGUI (){}).

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
public class Main : EditorWindow {
    [MenuItem ("Window/Panorama Terrain Tools")]
    public static void ShowWindow () {
        m_WindowMain = (Main) GetCustomWindow (true);
        // if(Main.m_WindowMain == null) { Main.m_WindowMain = (Main) Main.GetCustomWindow (true); }
        m_WindowMain.Show ();
    }

    public static Main GetCustomWindow (bool focus) {
        return GetWindow<Main> ("Работа с объектами и terrain", focus);
    }


    void OnEnable () {

    }
    void OnGUI () {
     ...
    }

    void SomeMethod(){
     Debug.Log("метод который надо вызывать после метода void OnGUI () {}");
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Почему его нельзя вызвать в самом конце OnGUI?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Потому что его надо вызвать один раз и все . как  void OnEnable (){} вызывается один раз

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Вообще ещё хочу писать красивый код . Думал может есть способ вызывать в конце отрисовки  OnGUI , как метод  void OnEnable () {} вызывается в начале , так и какой то способ вызывать в конце , так же один раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через события и отписку после первого срабатывания:

```
public abstract class ExtendedEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
    public event Action OnAfterDrawingGUI;

    private void OnGUI () {
        DrawContents();
        OnAfterDrawingGUI?.Invoke();
    }

    protected abstract void DrawContents();
}

public class MyWindow : ExtendedEditorWindow {
    private void OnEnable() {
        OnAfterDrawingGUI += SomeMethod;
    }

    protected override void DrawContents() {
        // Drawing contents
    }

    private void SomeMethod() {
        // отписываемся после первого срабатывания
        OnAfterDrawingGUI -= SomeMethod;

        Debug.Log("SomeMethod()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо завтра на работе проверю ... Вы как всегда выручаете

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-run-a-method-in-unity-after-rendering-the-gui-void-ongui-in-editorwindow.915725/

Comment: @IvanTriumphov решение с `delayCall` неплохое, но, как по мне, логичнее такими вещами управлять в классе, чем через глобальное событие :)